# files from *.rc are not refreshed when compiling/building

Tags: delphi, rc

I have a file that needs to be refreshed every days, linked into a rc file this way :

`docs.rc`

```
  file RCDATA "C:\folder\myfile.ext"
```

I understand that it refreshes the resources itself if changes are made in my *.rc file... only.
The only way i found to be sure that the resource is refreshed is removing it, compiling, setting it back and compiling again.

Any piece of advice, pre-compiling command or anything better ?

Thanks !

Using Delphi XE2 Enterprise.

[edit]

of course i forgot this line from project code :

```
{$R 'docs.res' 'docs.rc'}
```

Comment: Building the project should be enough, are you sure it doesn't link in the changet file?

Comment: What you haven't shown is how you're invoking RC. Do you have a {$R} declaration in your project that you haven't shown us or an RC node  in the project view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your project. Go to `Project` Menu then select `Resources and Images` item. Then add your resources to the list instead of RC file.

It will solve your problem.

Comment: this feature does not appear to be available in Delphi 2007

Comment: Yes, this has been added to newer versions. In older versions you have to do it manually using .RES and .RC files.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pre-Build event and compile rc-files "manually" with brcc32.exe

Comment: Not necessary. Delphi can compile it for you, if you just add it to the project like Vahid said, or you can use the old `{$R foo.rc foo.res}` syntax in the .dpr file.

Comment: @WarrenP : That's how I used to do it too, but it does not appear to work anymore in Delphi XE2... (IIRC it stopped working some versions before that, probably 2010-ish)